# Converting Array into Object

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

I have a list that's organized like : ["ImageUrl","Year","Credit","ImageUrl","Year","Credit"...] and I want to display a horizontal scrollview of the images with the year/credit below. I've tried using a while loop within SwiftUI like this but I receive an error stating the *Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'*.

Here's my code:

```
struct ImageList : View {
    
    var listOfImages : Array<String>
    @State var i = 0
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
        while i < listOfImages.count {
            VStack(){
                KFImage(listOfImages[i]).resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 300).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                Text(listOfImages[i+1])
                Text(listOfImages[i+2])
                }
            i = i+3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to update how the list's are organized because it's already coming from our backend. My initial plan was to import the list elements into a list of objects like this:

```
struct HistoricalImages: Hashable {
    let link : String
    let year : String
    let credit : String    
}
```

but i'm not sure how to convert it effectively. Any help is appreciated. This is my first StackOverflow post so please let me know if anything needs to be added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an index range to slice the array to groups of 3 elements and create an object of each slice

```
var index = 0
var items = [HistoricalImages]()
while index < array.count {
    let end = index + 2
    if end > array.count {
        break
    }

    let slice = Array(array[index...end])
    items.append(HistoricalImages(link: slice[0], year: slice[1], credit: slice[2]))
    index += 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `while` loop within the `body` property:

```
while i < listOfImages.count {
...
}
```

You need to use a `ForEach` instead:

```
ForEach(0..<listOfImages.count) { idx in
...
}
```